# WSO2 API Manager & Tomcat manager-gui role

Tags: wso2

Is it possible to add the Tomcat manager web application into WSO2 API Manager. I need this application due to the fact that our monitor-tools expect this default application from Tomcat to monitor this ennvironment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following solution:

- Downloaded Tomcat ZIP file
- Extracted the manager application from zip file (apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\manager )
- Moved this manager directory to my WSO2 installation ($WSO2_HOME/repository/deployment/server/webapps)
- Added the roles manager-gui, manager-script into WSO2
- Add user to WSO2 and assign these roles to this user
- Restart WSO2

Access the Tomcat WSO2 Manager application via: http(s)://yourhost:port/manager